# SQLite don't order by date

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I need a selection of all the elements of the table, sorted according to the column where there are dates

this is the table create code:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME +" ( "+
            " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
            " "+ COLUMN_LIST +" TEXT,"+
            " "+ COLUMN_PRICE + " TEXT,"+
            " "+ COLUMN_EXPIRY + " NUMERIC,"+
            " "+ COLUMN_DATE +" NUMERIC,"+
            " f_k INTEGER,"+
            " FOREIGN KEY(f_k) REFERENCES user(id)"+
            " ON DELETE CASCADE"+
            ")";
```

This is the code to insert elements in the column that I need to be ordered:

```
try{
    VAL.put( COLUMN_EXPIRY, String.valueOf( new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" ).parse( items.get( 2 ).toString() ) ) );
}catch( ParseException e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the `items.get( 2 ).toString()` is `stringDate` variable:

```
int day = date.getDayOfMonth();
int month = date.getMonth() + 1;
int year = date.getYear();

stringDate = Integer.toString( day ) +"-"+ Integer.toString( month ) +"-"+ Integer.toString( year );
```

the code of select element:

```
final String QUERY = SELECT_ALL + t;
final String ORDER = " ORDER BY DATE("+ COLUMN_EXPIRY +") DESC";
final Cursor RESULT = DB.rawQuery( QUERY + ORDER, null );
```

the result does not satisfy me. the dates are not in order.
Also some elements of the column are null and I would put down the list using a different order taken by another column.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
" "+ COLUMN_EXPIRY +" NUMERIC,"
```

And u store

```
String.valueOf( new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" ).parse( items.get( 2 ).toString() ) ) );
```

It is completely wrong because you are getting String.valueOf(date)

---

You can use instead

```
" "+ COLUMN_DATE +" INTEGER,"
```

And get long value in milliseconds of your date which is casted to string

```
String.valueOf( new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" ).parse( items.get( 2 )).getTime()) ) );
```

Then it should work

UPDATE

Dont forget to change

```
final String ORDER = " ORDER BY DATE("+ COLUMN_EXPIRY +") DESC";
```

to

```
final String ORDER = " ORDER BY "+ COLUMN_EXPIRY +" DESC";
```

Comment: to use getTime() i tranform items.get( 2 ) from string to Date?

Comment: @RESOLE no, forgot bracked, fixed

Comment: this return milliseconds, not date

Comment: @RESOLE so what? If you store milliseconds - not date you can sort by milliseconds, and you can easily get Date from that epoch milliseconds. Like new Date(milliseconds);

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a complex query you could try storing the elements of the date in separate fields:

```
    " "+ COLUMN_EXPIRY_day + " NUMERIC,"+
    " "+ COLUMN_EXPIRY_month + " NUMERIC,"+
    " "+ COLUMN_EXPIRY_year + " NUMERIC,"+
```

And your query's Order By clause:

```
ORDER BY COLUMN_EXPIRY_year, COLUMN_EXPIRY_month, COLUMN_EXPIRY_day
```

Comment: is a solution that might work, but it would require more computation time

Answer (score -2):

When creating table, your **COLUMN_EXPIRY** is having improper data type to be treated as date/time.

Change it as below and you should be good to go:

```
...
" "+ COLUMN_EXPIRY + " DATETIME,"+
...
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem because I have already tried this solution

Comment: read this: http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-insert-datetime-value-in-sqlite-database/